# Transposing and Grouping Rows into columns in a SQL query

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables (SQL scripts with data):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item_Master](  
[Item_Name] [varcha`enter code here`r](20) NOT NULL,  
[Item_Cost] [int] NULL,  
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item_Master] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
(  
    [Item_Name] ASC  
)  
)  

GO  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemAnalysis]  
(  
Item_Name nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,  
Analysis_Type nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,  
Item_Quantity int NOT NULL,  
Analysis_Date date NOT NULL  
)  

GO  

insert Item_Master (Item_Name, Item_Cost)   
values ('item1', 2)     
insert Item_Master (Item_Name, Item_Cost)  
values ('item2', 3)  

insert ItemAnalysis (Item_Name, Analysis_Type, Item_Quantity, Analysis_Date)   
values ('item1', 'A', 10, '2012-01-14')  
insert ItemAnalysis (Item_Name, Analysis_Type, Item_Quantity, Analysis_Date)   
values ('item1', 'B', 12, '2012-01-14')  
insert ItemAnalysis (Item_Name, Analysis_Type, Item_Quantity, Analysis_Date)   
values ('item2', 'A', 11, '2012-01-14')  
insert ItemAnalysis (Item_Name, Analysis_Type, Item_Quantity, Analysis_Date)   
values ('item2', 'B', 14, '2012-01-14')  
insert ItemAnalysis (Item_Name, Analysis_Type, Item_Quantity, Analysis_Date)   
values ('item1', 'A', 9, '2012-02-11')  
insert ItemAnalysis (Item_Name, Analysis_Type, Item_Quantity, Analysis_Date)     
values ('item1', 'B', 11, '2012-02-11')  
insert ItemAnalysis (Item_Name, Analysis_Type, Item_Quantity, Analysis_Date)  
values ('item2', 'A', 20, '2012-02-11')  
insert ItemAnalysis (Item_Name, Analysis_Type, Item_Quantity, Analysis_Date)   
values ('item2', 'B', 7, '2012-02-11')
```

I need the output like this:

```
Item_Name| Item_Cost| Analysis_Date| Type_A_Quantity| Type_B_Quantity  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
item1|2|2012-01-14|10|12  
item2|3|2012-01-14|11|14  
item1|2|2012-02-11|9|11  
item2|3|2012-02-11|20|7
```

There is no regularity on when the analysis would be done (e.g. it cal be done weekly or monthly etc) but whenever the analysis is done it is done for all the items on a single day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5035f/5)

```
SELECT
    m.Item_Name,
    m.Item_Cost,
    a.Analysis_Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Analysis_Type = 'A' THEN Item_Quantity ELSE 0 END) as Type_A_Quantity,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Analysis_Type = 'B' THEN Item_Quantity ELSE 0 END) as Type_B_Quantity
FROM Item_Master m
JOIN ItemAnalysis a
    ON m.Item_Name = a.Item_Name
GROUP BY m.Item_Name, m.Item_Cost, a.Analysis_Date
```